# R Conditionally transform data frame from long to wide based on multiple unique variables

Tags: r, dataframe, reshape2, dcast

I know this is a very common post on SO but I have been spending a little too much time researching a way to transform a data frame from long form to wide form and haven't quite found a post(s) to guide me through the entire process.  I have a data frame similar in structure to the reprex below but with 100+ rows.  Basically, the same structure is repeated every 9 rows but with different variables. However, in order to keep this post as readable as possible, I'm providing the first 9 rows of my data frame. Please note that each `Id` is related to a `Name` and `Pos`.

```
library("reshape2")

test <- data.frame(
Id = c("9644", "14513", "9874",
     "12363", "9673", "9538", 
     "9585", "23447", "40396"),
Pos = c("SG", "SF", "PF", "C", "PG", "SF",
           "SG", "PF", "PG"),
Name = c("John", "James", "Bob", "Sam",
         "Mark", "Andrew", "Bobby", "Elaine", "Jerry"),
Score = c(55.66, 43.82, 37.35, 40.59,
        35.15, 27.45, 28.82, 28.95,
        34.98),
Sal = c(60000, 60000, 60000, 60000,
         60000, 60000, 60000, 60000,
         60000),
Total = c(332.77, 332.77, 332.77, 332.77,
        332.77, 332.77, 332.77, 332.77,
        332.77),
TmNumber = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1))
```

I would like to transform my columns and variables into this format:

```
desiredDF <- data.frame(
  TmNum = "1",
  Id1 = "9644", Id2 = "14513", Id3 = "9874", Id4 = "12363",
  Id5 = "9673", Id6 = "9538", Id7 = "9585", Id8 = "23447",
  Id9 = "403396",
  PG = "Mark", PG = "Jerry", SG = "John", SG = "Bobby",
  SF = "James", SF = "Andrew", PF = "Bob", PF = "Elaine",
  C = "Sam",
  Score1 = "55.66", Score2 = "43.82", Score3 = "3735", Score4 = "40.59",
  Score5 = "35.15", Score6 = "27.45", Score7 = "28.82", Score8 = "28.95",
  Score9 = "34.98",
  Sal = "60000",
  Total = "332.77"
)
```

I have tried the following code (and a few more failed attempts):

```
test2 <- dcast(test, TmNum ~ Pos, value.var = "Name")
> test2
TmNum C PF PG SF SG
1     1 1  2  2  2  2
```

Thank you!

Comment: If you want one row dataframe, try `data.frame(t(unlist(test)))`

Comment: @RonakShah  I'm updating my question to reflect the fact that my data frame contains several rows of data (in similar format) and the reprex I provided was a snippet of the entire data frame that's 1000 rows long.  This is why I was looking into casting from long to wide.  Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @Ferroao I have added a better example of what my desired data frame should look like.

Comment: @Ferroao you are correct that each `Id` is related to a `Name`. I tried your proposed solution, however, it resulted in my dataframe essentially collapsing down to one row. It's a bit dissaponting to hear that there might not be a solution. I'll keep looking around and maybe I can reshape my df in a way that makes it possible to transform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try merging several dcast's:

```
library(reshape2)

Ave <- function(lab, x, g, FUN = seq_along) paste0(lab, ave(format(x), g, FUN = FUN))

L <- list(
  dcast(data = transform(test, ID = Ave("Id", Id, TmNumber)),
    TmNumber ~ ID, value.var = "Id"),
  dcast(data = transform(test, Pos = Ave("", Pos, TmNumber, make.unique)),
    TmNumber ~ Pos, value.var = "Name"),
  dcast(data = transform(test, SCORE = Ave("Score", Score, TmNumber)),
    TmNumber + Sal + Total ~ SCORE, value.var = "Score"))

Reduce(function(x, y) merge(x, y, by = 1), L)
```

giving:

```
  TmNumber  Id1   Id2  Id3   Id4  Id5  Id6  Id7   Id8   Id9  C   PF   PF.1   PG
1        1 9644 14513 9874 12363 9673 9538 9585 23447 40396 Sam Bob Elaine Mark
   PG.1    SF   SF.1   SG  SG.1   Sal  Total Score1 Score2 Score3 Score4 Score5
1 Jerry James Andrew John Bobby 60000 332.77  55.66  43.82  37.35  40.59  35.15
  Score6 Score7 Score8 Score9
1  27.45  28.82  28.95  34.98
```

Comment: this looks very promising and I will give it a try later today. I think a sort on the original df plus your solution will produce the output I'm after.

Comment: this is very close to working exactly like I need it to except that the `Id` columns fill in with `Id1`, `Id2`, `Id3`, etc instead of preserving the original values (i.e., `9644`, `14513`).  Playing around with the code now to see if I can figure it out.

Comment: The first value.var was supposed to be "Id", not "ID".  Have fixed.

Comment: Fantastic! Exactly what I was looking for.